# Nginx rewrite gives 404

Tags: nginx

On a server with Ubuntu 20.04 and nginx 1.18.0 using ISPConfig 3.2 I have the following configuration for my Wordpress website:

```
location /api {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php last;
}

location ~* ^/index\.php$ {
    break;
}
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;

location /user {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    rewrite ^/user/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/master?$ /index.php/master/?userid=$2 redirect;
    rewrite ^/user/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/chief?$ /index.php/chief/?userid=$2 redirect;
    rewrite ^/user/([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ /user/?userid=$2 redirect;
}
```

The redirect for e.g. /user/john/123 to /user/?userid=123 is working as expected.
But I do not want a redirect but to keep the URL as it is and show the content of the internally rewritten URL. So I tried to change `redirect` to `break` or `last` but both changes are resulting in a 404.

```
...
location /user {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    rewrite ^/user/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/master?$ /index.php/master/?userid=$2 last;
    rewrite ^/user/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/chief?$ /index.php/chief/?userid=$2 last;
    rewrite ^/user/([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ /user/?userid=$2 last;
}
```

Why is it working with the redirect but not without?

Edit

Another try:

```
location /api {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php last;
}

location ~* ^/index\.php$ {
    break;
}
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;

location /user {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @userrules;
}

location @userrules {
    rewrite ^/user/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/master?$ /index.php/master/?userid=$2 redirect;
    rewrite ^/user/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/chief?$ /index.php/chief/?userid=$2 redirect;
    rewrite ^/user/([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ /index.php/user/?userid=$2 redirect;
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?$args last;
}
```

Same result - if I remove the `redirect` it results in a 404.
The resulting page e.g. `/user/?userid=203` works but I would like to keep the readable URLs.

Comment: This might help: https://serverfault.com/a/132320

Comment: There is a good explanation, thanks. But unfortunately it did not help. I think the problem is not with the rewrite itself but with `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;`. I guess the index.php is not used after rewrite which might be the cause.

Comment: your edit just worsens whole situation, sorry. Basically you can't rewrite and keep old url at the same time, there is no logic. Browser shows url it loads, nginx redirects you to new url and its content. You can't achieve both opposite targets.

Comment: I do not think that this is true. First of all it did work with the same website on IIS server before. Furthermore it works with `rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?$args last;` without any redirect. Also I have working configurations with the same approach on Apache.